# How to convert from Java String to Date of format hh:mm:ss?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

1. From one of my web service method call returns Strings which are float values:

   Ex: 375.677, 61.47 etc.
2. These values are nothing but minutes 931 and 500 seconds.
3. But I have to convert this String to Date format of HH:MM:SS which means like this: Ex: 06:20:04.

I have looked into stack exchange questions and tried a solution below. But that is returning the invalid values. Here is the code I tried:

```
    float f = Float.parseFloat("375.677");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) f);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) ((f * 60) % 60));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, (int) ((f * 3600) % 3600));

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance,
 Saku

Comment: Your point 2. is confusing.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? It includes a new date/time API.

Comment: @Pickle - If my string value is 375.50, this value is displaying in minutes like 375 minutes 50 secs ... instead of this minutes I need to convert it as hours:minutes:seconds ..

Comment: @Andy Thomas - Yes I am using Java 8.

Comment: So `375.677` would mean 375 minutes and 677 seconds? If that's the case then I'd suggest you parse that manually, e.g. split at the dot and parse the two integer values, then convert it to seconds (that is minutes * 60 + seconds) and create a date out of it.

Comment: @AndyThomas - I will try out this

Comment: Btw, I'd question the quality of that webservice if the times are that odd (especially with .677 meaning 677 seconds). Or is it actually .677 minutes, i.e. 60 * .677 ~ 41 seconds?

Comment: @Andy - These are some of the values: 369.927,109.033,530.217,166.074,10725.141,1455.347,22.001 ... The first value before dot is sure Minutes ..

Comment: So "375.677" means 375 minutes and ... what does the 677 mean? 677 seconds or 0.677 minutes? (By the way, your sample code looks like it's treating 375.677 as a real number of *hours*.)

Comment: Could you post multiple sample of input / output?

Comment: @Andy - Not sure you might be correct.

Comment: @Tunaki - I have applied the below code by Aso Le - Inputs are - 6.417, 0.000,24.541 and the outputs I am getting is wrong. Its - 09:12:57,09:00:00,09:33:01. This values should be like for 1st one:00:06:417 as seconds

Comment: @Sakuntala What does `00:06:417` mean? What does 417 seconds mean?

Comment: @Sakuntala - We can't help you convert the input to *hh:mm:ss* without knowing what the input represents, and, given *ss* > 59, a precise definition of the desired output. Until then, any answers are guesses.

Comment: @Andy - If seconds >59 then need to consider those 60 seconds into a minute and then calculate the total hours,minutes and seconds ... The below code from pepan is working fine. I tried for some inputs and calculates whether its converting properly. That's working.

Answer (score 1):

Only JDK 1.5 is necessary.

```
    String input = "375.677";
    int mins = 0;
    int secs = 0;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ".");
    if (st.hasMoreTokens()) mins = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    if (st.hasMoreTokens()) secs = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    if (st.hasMoreTokens()) throw new IllegalStateException("Second dot not allowed!");

    int seconds = mins*60+secs;
    int ss = seconds % 60;
    seconds = seconds / 60;
    int mm = seconds % 60;
    seconds = seconds / 60;
    int hh = seconds;

    System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh, mm, ss));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean minutes before the point, and seconds after it, where the minutes go up to 931 and seconds go up to 500. If so, try

```java
float f = Float.parseFloat("375.677");
int m = ((int) f);
int s = ((int) (f * 1000)) % 1000;
// handle second overflow
m += s / 60;
s %= 60;
// handle minute overflow
int h = m / 60;
m %= 60;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, s);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: I tried the code. But I am getting these values: 6.417 as 09:12:57,0.000 as 09:00:00 and 24.541 as 09:33:01 which are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to seconds:

```
    String timeString = "234.34";
    String[] timeValuesAfterSplit = timeString.split("\\.");
    int minutesToSeconds = Integer.parseInt(timeValuesAfterSplit[0]) * 60;
    int totalSeconds = minutesToSeconds + Integer.parseInt(timeValuesAfterSplit[1]);
```

Now get the time in the given format using LocalTime as:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(totalSeconds);
```

And then the format that you need could be obtained by calling `toString()` on `localTime`.